# Add-Type -path "c:\Oracle\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll" fails in Powershell

Tags: powershell, oracle11g

I'm attempting to follow the instructions according to [this post for making an Oracle connection in PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/04/use-oracle-odp-net-and-powershell-to-simplify-data-access.aspx).  When I try to load the Oracle .dll I get a operation not supported error.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Add-Type -path "C:\Oracle\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Oracle\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll' or one of its dependencies.
 Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:9
+ Add-Type <<<<  -path "C:\Oracle\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Type], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was resolved by adding the correct entries in TNSNAMES.ORA and restarting powershell.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Oracle\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
```

verify to have access to folder and unlocked the file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by unlocked.  I have verified that the appropriate permissions are available to the file.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy right click on you dll file if is locked there's a button 'unlock' click on it. if you has download it, maybe is locked for secutity reasons.

Comment: It's not locked.  I've even tried rebooting my system and making sure my execution policy is set to unrestricted thought I have a feeling it doesn't apply to this situation.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy Can help more of this, I'm sorry. Have you tested the dll as reference in a visual studio project? Maybe file is corrupted?